# Sort array after specific model with php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an array after specific model and need a little help.

The model array is:

```
$model = array('S','D','P','X','M');
```

the array I want to sort is:

```
$array = array('S','M','X','P');
```

and the final result should be:

```
$result = array('S','P','X','M');
```

the `$array` may not contain all the values from `$model`, it may contain different combination and also fewer values.

I tried:

```
$result = array(); // result array
foreach($model as $val){ // loop
    $result[array_search($val, $array)] = $val; // adding values
}
print_r($result);
```

This sort but replace S with D result will be

```
$result = array('D','P','X','M');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the way I'd go:

```
$model=array('S','D','P','X','M');
$array=array('S','M','X','P');

$result = array(); // result array
foreach($model as $val){
    // if it exists in the array
    if (array_search($val, $array) !== false)
        // add the value to the result array
        $result[] = $val;
}
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => S
    [1] => P
    [2] => X
    [3] => M
)
```